# How to change the download location using python and selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've written the code to download files for each month in a range of years for every precinct and place. However, since I can't change the name of the files through selenium, I was hoping to download each place's files into a separate folder. Here's my code

```
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('download.default_directory=/Users/name/Downloads/' + p)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="/Users/name/Downloads/chromedriver")
        driver.get("https://jpwebsite.harriscountytx.gov/PublicExtracts/search.jsp")
```

where `p` is the id of a particular precinct and place. Unfortunately the files are downloaded to `/Users/name/Downloads`. I've added chromedriver to `PATH` and just used

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

but that gives me this:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use timestamp to create new directory. Also use preference dictionary for chrome options with `prompt_for_download` and `directory_upgrade` params. try below example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
"download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\XXXX\downdir\stamp"+timestr,
"download.prompt_for_download": False,
"download.directory_upgrade": True
}

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://jpwebsite.harriscountytx.gov/PublicExtracts/search.jsp")
```

Comment: Works fine, can you explain directory upgrade ?

Comment: It is related to change in download dir by means of an upgrade.
see the complete documentation on this link  : https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will work smoothly

```
import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {'download.default_directory' : 'path for your folder that you want'}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code it works for me, just create a profile for chrome and define the download location for the tests

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=D:/Sele_Downloads")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://jpwebsite.harriscountytx.gov/PublicExtracts/search.jsp")
```